# How to pass Json string with variable in c#?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

```
string a;

string b;

string jSonContent = @"{""fields"":{""summary"":""summary"" , ""description"": ""modified.""}}";
```

I want **a** instead of **summary** and **b** instead of **modified**. It works if I replace summary but gives errors if I replace both.

The edited code is, **string jSonContent = @"{""fields"":{""summary"":"+ "\""+ a+ "\"" +" , ""description"": "+ "\""+ b+ "\"" +"}}";** It's not giving any error, summary field is getting updated, but the description field is not.

Please revert. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a JSON library such as Json.NET to construct the JSON, rather than trying to use string operations.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the *contents* of variables `a` and `b` as values of those JSON properties?

Comment: Also please show the code you tried with that replacing, and what those "errors" were exactly.

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, I want the values of **a** and **b** to be passed to the server.

Comment: @HansKesting The edited code is, **string jSonContent = @"{""fields"":{""summary"":"+ "\""+ a+ "\"" +" , ""description"": "+ "\""+ b+ "\"" +"}}";
It's not giving any error, summary field is getting updated, but the description field is not.

Comment: So please edit the question, instead of adding it as a comment - and it's very confusing when you initially say "but gives errors" and now you're saying there *aren't* any errors.

Comment: use newtonsoft library.  e.g. for serialization ----> var mystring =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.MyClassList);
-----------for deserialization:----->
 List<MyClass> myclasslist1= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectmystring typeof(List<MyClass>)) as List<MyClass>;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string a = "a";
string b = "b";

string jSonContent = (@"{""fields"":{""summary"":""summary"" , ""description"": ""modified.""}}").Replace(@":""summary""", a).Replace("modified.", b);
```

Comment: BTW, why are there these many quotes in the **replace** part? What do they mean? The colon and the single quotes?

Comment: actually in C# we have to replace " we use previously '''

Comment: @HareshKola it suddenly isn't working for summary. description is working fine.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Use a JSON library instead to handle JSON. This won't escape anything in `a` or `b`.

Comment: use this  string jSonContent = (@"{""fields"":{""summary"":""summary"" , ""description"": ""modified.""}}").Replace(@":""summary""", a).Replace("modified.", b);

Comment: "its must works always" - not if `a` contains backslashes or other things that would make this invalid JSON. **This is simply a bad approach, and should be abandoned.**

Answer (score 4):

I highly suggest you to use JSON library, for example [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

First of all, you'll be able to work with strongly typed objects, in addition you will avoid typos and similar bugs since the serializer will do the serialization for you.

```
public void Test()
{
    string a = ""; //content of 'a' variable
    string b = ""; //content of 'b' variable

    var obj = new RootObject();
    obj.Fields = new Fields();

    obj.Fields.Summary = a;
    obj.Fields.Description = b;

    var jsonOutput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, typeof(RootObject));
}

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Note: If you don't want to create unnecessary types, you can work directly with `JObject`, this is one of possible uses:

```
var jobj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(new {
    fields = new {
        summary = a,
        description = b
    }
});
var jsonOutput = jobj.ToString();
```

Comment: Not that you need to create extra types like this - I'd just use `JObject` unless this is needed in multiple places.

Comment: I have them all.. The only problem I am facing is with passing these variables in Json string. Also, it works fine if I pass only summary(with variable), it also works fine if I pass both of them, but with static data, the problem is with making both of them dynamic.

Comment: That "<content>" really was irritating. Thought you want to insert xml-tags :)

Comment: @OleAlbers here you go :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use string.Format or string.concate Method

```
string jSonContent = string.Concat("{\"fields\":{\"summary\":","\"",a,"\" , \"description\": \"",b,"\"}}");
```

Comment: Those are bad ideas though, as they won't perform any escaping etc required for JSON. It's much better to use a dedicated JSON library.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, but here only two field so string Concat do same thing

Comment: And what if the contents of `a` contains a double quote, for example? Then you've got invalid JSON. The number of fields is irrelevant - this solution is the JSON equivalent of building a SQL string dynamically instead of using parameterized SQL. Just don't do it.

Comment: I assume a is server side variable

Comment: I have no idea what you think that has to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

Use string fromat `$""`

String format allow you to replace values from your variables into a string. E.g.

```
string name = "Bruno";
string result = $"My name is {name}";
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The output will be

```
My name is Bruno
```

In your case you just have to escape the json brackets with a double bracket `{{`

```
string a = "this is a sumary";
string b = "this is a description";
string jSonContent = $"{{\"fields\":{{\"summary\":\"{a}\" , \"description\": \"{b}\"}}}}";

Console.WriteLine(jSonContent);
```

the output is

```
{"fields":{"summary":"this is a sumary" , "description": "this is a description"}}
```

However I strongly advise to not build your json strings manually, use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or any other NuGet Packages.

Comment: No, don't build JSON like this. Use a JSON library instead. Consider what will happen if `name` contains backslashes, or quotes, or anything else that needs escaping.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've just answered to what he asked for. Also I advised to use a JSON lib instead. He didn't specified for what purpose he needed this.

Comment: Would you do the same if someone asked you how to build up a SQL string with values? This is basically the equivalent. The OP appears to want a JSON document with two values which are specified using strings. Using string formatting is a very dangerous way of approaching this.